# c++ - replace this by new object

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, this, valgrind, new-operator

Basically I want the this-pointer in foo() to point at a new object which points at *this.
Since I can't change the this-pointer, I am creating a new object which just takes over the array from *this and then empty *this and let it point at the newobject.

```
struct SomeClass{
  int* value;
  SomeClass* child;

  SomeClass() : value{nullptr}, child{nullptr}{}

  void foo(){
    SomeClass* otherobject = new SomeClass;
    otherobject->value = value;
    value = nullptr;
    child = otherobject;
  }

  ~SomeClass(){
    if(child){
      child->~SomeClass();
    }
    delete[] value;
  }
};

int main() {
  SomeClass objekt;
  objekt.value = new int[10];
  for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    objekt.value[i] = i;
  
  objekt.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that valgrind tells me the program had memory leaks.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: `this` never appears in the code you're showing. Neither does `x`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Meh. I think it depends a lot on what your class is supposed to be. A linked list with `std::unique_ptr` is a bit of a headache, as you can only own the head or tail, and not both, and definitely nothing in between. I would tweak the wording to *prefer* `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "*`value = nullptr;` in `foo` means that `delete[] value;` won't delete anything and you leak the array created by `objekt.value = new int[10];`*" - not true, since the array was *transferred* to `otherobject`, so it will be `delete[]`'ed when that object is destroyed. The real leak is that object is not having its memory freed properly.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't notice that transfer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, can you also tell me why delete child solves the problem? I thought it would do the exact same thing as what I did.

Comment: @Salominius see the edit to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `~SomeClass()` destructor, you need to change:

```cpp
if(child){
    child->~SomeClass();
}
```

to:

```
delete child;
```

There is more to destructing an object then just calling its destructor. The memory used by the object needs to be freed as well. That happens *outside* of the destructor. The destructor itself doesn't know HOW the object was allocated (In automatic memory? In dynamic memory?), so calling the destructor directly, as you are, will not free the memory used by the object. But calling `delete` on the object will call its destructor AND free its memory (provided it was allocated with `new` to begin with, as it is in your example).

---

Also, `SomeClass` is not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).  You need to add (or delete) a copy constructor and copy assignment operator, and a move constructor and move assignment operator, eg:

```cpp
struct SomeClass{
  int* value = nullptr;
  SomeClass* child = nullptr;

  SomeClass() = default;

  // delete'd since we don't know how many ints to copy...
  SomeClass(const SomeClass &src) = delete;

  SomeClass(SomeClass &&src) : value(src.value) {
    src.value = nullptr;
  }

  // delete'd since we don't know how many ints to copy...
  SomeClass& operator=(const SomeClass &) = delete;

  SomeClass& operator=(SomeClass &&rhs){
    std::swap(value, rhs.value);
    return *this;
  }

  ~SomeClass(){
    delete child;
    delete[] value;
  }

  void foo(){
    delete child;
    child = new SomeClass(std::move(*this));
  }
};
```

That being said, this can be made better/safer if you used `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` instead:

```cpp
struct SomeClass{
  std::vector<int> value;
  std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> child;

  SomeClass(int size = 0) : value(size) {
  }

  SomeClass(const SomeClass &src) : value(src.value) {
  }

  SomeClass(SomeClass &&src) : value(std::move(src.value)) {
  }

  SomeClass& operator=(SomeClass rhs){
    std::swap(value, rhs.value);
    return *this;
  }

  void foo(){
    child = std::make_unique<SomeClass>(std::move(*this));
  }
};

int main() {
  SomeClass objekt(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    objekt.value[i] = i;
  
  objekt.foo();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to move `child` in your move members.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux typically yes, one should move *all* members. But in this case, I intentionally omitted `child`, due to the weird ownership semantics of the OP's original code. Obviously, this is not a good way to write code.

Comment: someclass was just supposed to show my problem as simplefied as possible. this is why it might not be complete.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I just want you to know how thankfull I am! I am working on a bigger project where for certain reasons arrays and raw pointers seemed to be the best solution. However I have been trying to debug this for an eternity and your solution just solved everything! Thanks a lot!